# Sharing photos on Instagram

Tags: instagram

About a year ago the question was asked about enabling the sharing of images from a website to Instagram - the same way you can for Facebook or Twitter through PHP API.  Has anything changed?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you still cannot post images to Instagram through their API. The only method they allow is through the use of their mobile applications.

Comment: Any update? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65575462/sharing-on-instagram-on-pc-web